# how to get a regex pattern to match consecutively?

Tags: regex

Consider this simple example

```
http://time.com/this-time-is-different
```

Here I would like to match sequences such as `this-time-is-different`.

That is, any sequence of a word followed by a `-`, with this sequence being repeated at least three times. So in the example, the sequence `word-` is repeated three times only with `this-time-is-different`

However, when I use `[-\w]{3,}` I get too many matches, such as `http` which is not even followed by a `-`

[image]

What is wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: `(\w+-){3,}\w+` a word followed by a hyphen 3 times or more followed by a word. [Demo](https://regexr.com/3un8f)

Comment: thanks @Oram, that is an interesting alternative. What is the difference with the `non-capturing-group` solution?

Comment: It's a question of what you want to capture. Sometimes you don't want to have a lot of back references or you just want to optimize performance.
`(?:\w+-){3,}\w+` is with a non-capturing-group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[-\w]{3,}` pattern is a [*character class*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) matching a hyphen *or* a word char, three or more consecutive occurrences. So, it matches `-----w--`, `wwd234_23---` like strings and more. You see, these chars may come in any order.

You may use a grouping construct here:

```
\w+(?:-\w+){2,}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C3UHQe/1). Here, `(?:-\w+){2,}` is a [*non-capturing group*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) that matches 2 or more consecutive occurrences of a hyphen followed with one or more word chars.

**Details**

- `\w+` - one or more letters, digits or `_`
- `(?:-\w+){2,}` - a non-capturing group matching 2 or more consecutive occurrences of

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `\w+` - one or more letters, digits or `_`.

If the `-` can appear consecutively, like `a--b----d`, you may apply the `+` after `-` to also match 1 or more occurrences:

```
\w+(?:-+\w+){2,}
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C3UHQe/2).

Still, with the grouping construct, you ensure that `-`s should appear after at least 1 word char and they must be followed with at least 1 word chars.

Comment: thanks! i am not familiar with that. could you please explain?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I added details. Please let me know if anything is still unclear.

Comment: Thanks! that is much better. Still I have a noob question here. If `(?:-\w+){2,}` is not captured, then why am I still getting the full `this-time-is-different` match back? I do not get it

Comment: Because it is still matched and consumed.